# Why is there an error while starting pgAdmin 4 for postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

When I am trying to start pgAdmin 4 tool, it is showing:
Fatal error.
An error occured initialising the pgAdmin 4 server:
Failed to launch the application server, server thread exiting.

I am an absolute beginner. So please answer in details.

[image]

Comment: do you have a solution?

Answer (score -1):

It seems something wrong with pgAdmin 4，but the pg server works ok，you can try to use the SQL shell under PostGreSQL, or try another version of pgAdmin.